# How to get first and last day of the week with Moment.js?

Tags: angular, typescript, momentjs

How do I get the date of the first day of the week and the date of the last day of the week with Moment.js?

I need to get the date from the first day of the week to the date of the last day of the current week that I'm basing on the current day.

I read the documentation https://momentjs.com/docs/ and I found the **weekday ()** function, but I need to get the first day of the week and the last day of the week based on the current date, how do I do this using Moment?

I need this to filter the data of an Observable according to the period: Month, Week ...

```
var start_date = moment(this.start_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
var final_date = moment(this.final_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD')

this.transacoesList = this.transacoesList
  .filter((v) => {

    var release_date = moment(v.release_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD');

    if (moment(release_date).isBetween(start_date, final_date, null, '[]')) {
      return true;
    }
  });
```

Comment: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/, https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/end-of/.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are on the right track. The `weekday` function can be used to get the Monday and Friday of the current week.

```
var now = moment();
var monday = now.clone().weekday(1);
var friday = now.clone().weekday(5);
var isNowWeekday = now.isBetween(monday, friday, null, '[]');

console.log(`now: ${now}`);
console.log(`monday: ${monday}`);
console.log(`friday: ${friday}`);
console.log(`is now between monday and friday: ${isNowWeekday}`);
```

Direct link to the Moment.js docs on the `weekday` function here: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/weekday/

Comment: thanks, helped a lot, did not know the clone function ()

Comment: isn't monday at index 0, and friday at index 4?

Comment: @Ziarno, according to the linked documentation, `weekday` is locale aware. Depending on your locale, `weekday(0)` may be either Monday or Sunday. A more portable solution to always select Monday and Friday, regardless of locale, might be to use [`isoWeekday`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/iso-weekday/) (`isoWeekday(1)` and `isoWeekday(5)`).

Answer (score 18):

Getting first & last day of current week is as simple as the following:

```js
let currentDate = moment();
let weekStart = currentDate.clone().startOf('week');
let weekEnd = currentDate.clone().endOf('week');
```

Then you can format it

```js
let formatted = weekEnd.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

btw, I recommend **[Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/)** over **moment** for many reasons, one of the biggest one is immutability

Answer (score 1):

Moment's weekday function returns 0 when a day is the first day of the week for your locale. Therefore if the weekday is 0 for today's date, you're already at the first day of this week. If it's not 0, simply subtract that many days (Moment has functions for adding and subtracting days from a date) from the current date, and then you'll have the first day of the week.

Once you have the first day of the week, add 6 days to that and you'll have the last day of the week.